# Rails 3 - Devise 'Please enter an email address' popup message, even when validatable disabled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise

I cant seem to remove an annoying popup message which appears whenever an email address is invalid during the registration process.

I'm using Devise and I have tried removing :validatable but yet the message still pops up. Its must be javascript or something as the page doesn't reload, the message just appears in an ugly pink box.

The message simply reads " Please enter an email address ".

I cant find a single thing on the web or github about this issue, nor can I find any code in the devise app which might relate to this occurance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

probably this is due to the html5 validation built in your browser. Try to add `novalidate="novalidate"` to your form tag

Comment: Spot on thanks, I didnt know anything about that feature in browsers!

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Any thing else that might fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The devise view uses email_field in it's views. In order to override that, you need to generate the devise views into your app and override them with a standard text_field.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the field type from email_field to text_field in the view and the html5 email validation won't be triggered.

```
<%= f.text_field :email %>
```